# Texture import from different formats

Tags: texturing, materials, import, file-format, conversion

I had issues importing files to blender with the materials linked to different surfaces. I tried different file formats to have the different material textures retained, with very little success. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for this.

I used [CAD Assistant from Open Cascade](https://www.opencascade.com/products/cad-assistant) to convert the file to .glb format, which imported the model with materials linked to different surfaces.

Let me know if there is another way.